# How do i Execute javascript user-extention.js file in selenium directly?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-ide, selenium-grid

How do i Execute javascript in selenium directly? 
How we use command in java script?
In selenium Ide i sotre in selenium core extension (User-extention.js) file and
which file store in selenium ide extention....

[image]
I also run the below script but i can''t get result...

```
<body
<table>
<tr>
  <td>open</td>
  <td>https://www.google.com</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>40</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>0</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>while</td>
  <td>storedVars.looptimes &lt; = 20</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
  <td>selenium.browserbot.getCurrentWindow().scrollTo(o,${i})</td>
  <td></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td>store</td>
  <td>javascript{storedVars.looptimes++;}</td>
  <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
  <td>storeEval</td>
      <td>${i}+40</td>
      <td></td>
     </tr>
     <tr>
    <td>endWhile</td>
    <td></td>
    <td></td>
    <tr>
    </table>
    </body>
```

But i am getting error

> [error] Unexpected Exception: SyntaxError: syntax error. fileName -> chrome://flowcontrol/content/extensions/goto-sel-ide.js?1392885586314, lineNumber -> 134

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please check the code I have given.

```
http://seleniumworks.blogspot.in/2014/01/selenium-ide-data-driven.html
```

Also make sure,

- Active developer tools and
- Enable experimental features

checkboxes are Enabled.

---

**Prashanth Sams |** seleniumworks.com

Comment: Very use full answer. Also your blog is very informative..         My another questions is I am new in selenium ide working on command. My testing most of the work in mobile testing in device. If any possibility to use selenium in any online project. Or how to use selenium in mobile application.

Comment: I use APPIUM [tests can be written in your favorite Webdriver-compatible language] for testing Mobile Apps; If you need to work with APPIUM, please check my blog.

Comment: How do i work in APPIUM, Because i am using ubuntu (Linux) os. Most of the application in android, ios, and balckberry. For that i want to install emulator of particular device. Or any other option..By the way thanx for your value able reply.